# Please help me confirm the characters to this seal

Tags: meaning

chinese.stackexchange.com referred me here. One of their members told me that the reading in the seal is actually Japanese「知惠子/ちえこ」. Is this correct? Thank you!!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That indeed reads 「知恵子」 (a feminine name) in our traditional  stamp script named 印鑑書体{いんかんしょたい}.

(You may want to get rid of the image on the right as it is upside-down and it only makes your question look goofy.)